# ANDROID get data from previous activities

Tags: android

**THIS IS THE CONTINUATION OF MY QUESTION:**

I have a problem with getting something from the previous activity of my application. My case is, the previous activity, known as ListOfMeals, it has a listview (breakfast, morning snack, etc.) If I'd click breakfast and add meal, I'd click for list of foods like bread, fruits, veggies, etc. After that, it should add to my database. But what I have so far is this, please refer below:

```
case R.id.btFoodVegetableSave:
        String mealname = selected;

        String serving = calories.getText().toString();
        int i = Integer.parseInt(serving.replaceAll("[\\D]", ""));

        String servng = String.valueOf(i);

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
        String strDate = sdf.format(new Date());

        if ( ( mealname.isEmpty() || servng.isEmpty() ) ){

            // call for custom toast
            viewErrorToast();
        }

        else {

        boolean didItWork = true;

        try{

            BreakFastLog entry = new BreakFastLog(Baguettes_Bagels.this);
            entry.open();   
            entry.createEntry(mealname, servng, strDate);
            entry.close();

            }
            catch(Exception e){
                didItWork = false;
                viewErrorToast();
            }finally{
                if (didItWork){
                    viewBMRSavedToast();
                }

            }
        } // end of if else statement
        break;
```

**The structure of my app is like this:**

Activity A - List of Meals (listview = Breakfast, Morning Snack, etc) 
Activity B - Selected from Activity A (e.g., Morning Snack) where it has a button to add more food 
Activity C - List of meal categories (listview again: bread, pasta, etc) 
Activity D - Selected from Activity C (listview again: let's assume the user selected bread) 
Activity E - list of breads (it has listview again) 
Activity F - Selected from Activity E - (the user now selects for example white bread)

activity F has a save button, now that the user based on my example, selected morning snack, the data from activity f should be saved to morning snack table. How can I do this?

In my example, it only saves to my breakfast. But problem rises here when I'd choose morning snack not the breakfast. How can I get what the user selected from a previous activity and save it to its respective meal?

I know this has got something to do with this:

```
BreakFastLog entry = new BreakFastLog(Baguettes_Bagels.this);
        entry.open();   
        entry.createEntry(mealname, servng, strDate);
        entry.close();
```

I have to put if else statement, but I can't think of some clever ways to implement this. Thanks for your help in advance.

**NOTE:**

I've tried doing this:

```
 Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

            String breakfast = this.getIntent().getStringExtra("key_breakfast");
            String ms = this.getIntent().getStringExtra("key_morningsnack");
            String lunch = this.getIntent().getStringExtra("key_lunch");
            String as = this.getIntent().getStringExtra("key_afternoonsnack");
            String dinner = this.getIntent().getStringExtra("key_dinner");
            String es = this.getIntent().getStringExtra("key_eveningsnack");



            if( extras.equals(breakfast)){
                BreakFastLog entry = new BreakFastLog(Baguettes_Bagels.this);
                entry.open();   
                entry.createEntry(mealname, servng, strDate);
                entry.close();
            }
            else if( extras.equals(ms) ){ 
                MorningSnackLog entry = new MorningSnackLog(Baguettes_Bagels.this);
                entry.open();   
                entry.createEntry(mealname, servng, strDate);
                entry.close();
            }
            else if( extras.equals(lunch) ){
                LunchLog entry = new LunchLog(Baguettes_Bagels.this);
                entry.open();   
                entry.createEntry(mealname, servng, strDate);
                entry.close();
            }
            else if( extras.equals(as) ){
                AfternoonSnackLog entry = new AfternoonSnackLog(Baguettes_Bagels.this);
                entry.open();   
                entry.createEntry(mealname, servng, strDate);
                entry.close();
            }
            else if( extras.equals(dinner) ){
                DinnerLog entry = new DinnerLog(Baguettes_Bagels.this);
                entry.open();   
                entry.createEntry(mealname, servng, strDate);
                entry.close();
            }
            else if( extras.equals(es) ){
                EveningSnackLog entry = new EveningSnackLog(Baguettes_Bagels.this);
                entry.open();   
                entry.createEntry(mealname, servng, strDate);
                entry.close();
            }
```

to no avail. When i ran this and click the save button it is caught by my exception handler.

Comment: catch(Exception e){didItWork = false;
     viewErrorToast();

Comment: it's not saving to the table

Comment: what is the Exception? e.g. NullPointerException. post the logcat (and follow Steve B's answer)

Comment: yes it's nullpointerexception

Comment: ok...now what line number is it telling you the NPE occurs at? and can you pls somehow indicate that line in your post.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23325/discussion-between-betty-barnes-and-david-m)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if( extras.equals(breakfast))
```

will never return true. You are comparing a bundle to a string in this case. There are also some issues in the way you are setting up the bundle. Your bundle really only needs one property, the meal type (KEY_MEAL below). Try something like this...

```
public static final String MEAL_BREAKFAST = "breakfast";
public static final String MEAL_MORNING_SNACK = "morning_snack";
public static final String MEAL_LUNCH = "lunch";
public static final String KEY_MEAL = "meal";

Bundle bundle1 = new Bundle();
bundle1.putString(KEY_MEAL, MEAL_MORNING_SNACK); //change "MEAL_MORNING_SNACK" to whatever meal type was clicked

Intent i = new Intent();
i.putExtras(bundle1);
startActivity(i);
```

and in the next activity...

```
Bundle bundle2 = getIntent().getExtras();
if(bundle2.getString(KEY_MEAL).equals(MEAL_BREAKFAST))
    // meal is breakfast
else if(bundle2.getString(KEY_MEAL).equals(MEAL_MORNING_SNACK))
    // meal is morning snack
else if(bundle2.getString(KEY_MEAL).equals(MEAL_LUNCH))
    // meal is lunch
```

Comment: the first code you put above, so should I put it in my Activity A?

Comment: sorry I have many activities, and don't know where exactly to put the bundle2, is it on my last activity? thnx

Comment: The first block would go in activity A, and the second block in whatever activity was started from "startActivity(i);".  You can keep passing this same bundle from activity to activity if you need, adding and updating values in that bundle each time.

Answer (score 0):

We can pass the variables and values from one class to another through the use of `intent`.
The sample code I have used in my hotels project is as below. hope it will help you

```
Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), goal.class);
in.putExtra("h_id", h_id);
in.putExtra("lat1", lat1);
in.putExtra("lon1", lon1);
startActivity(in);
```

here in this way you can start next class execution with intent and passing values from present class to `goal class` with use of `in.putExtras("varible_name in new class, value ")`

and in the new class goal use

```
Intent in = getIntent();
        h_id = in.getStringExtra("h_id");
        lat1 = in.getDoubleExtra("lat1", 0);
        lon1 = in.getDoubleExtra("lon1", 0);
```